# Convincing the compiler that every index of an array will be initialized

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement the `Rand` trait for a buffer of 20 elements that implement the `Rand` trait themselves. I iterate the buffer through and initialize every element with a random value. However, I'm unable to convince the compiler that `buff` will end up fully initialized.

What should I do to get it to accept this?

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::{Rand, Rng};

struct Buf20<T>([T; 20]);

impl<T: Rand> Rand for Buf20<T> {
    fn rand<R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> Self {
        let mut buff : [T; 20];
        for element in &mut buff {
            *element = rng.gen();
        }
        Buf20(buff)
    }
}
```

Comment: If we someday have write-only &out references that turn to &mut on write, maybe, writing this kind of thing without unsafe becomes easier? But the iterator still needs to convince the compiler that it's gonna loop exhaustively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won’t be able to convince the compiler of this, because it’s not necessarily true.

There are two unknown types here, `T` and `R`, and their interactions could break things here. Here’s a couple of possible implementations of `Rand` and `Rng` that would make it blow up:

```rust
struct T(Box<u32>);

impl Rand for T {
    fn rand<R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> Self {
        T(Box::new(rng.next_u32()))
    }
}

struct R(u32);

impl Rng for R {
    fn next_u32(&mut self) -> u32 {
        let next = self.0;
        self.0 += 1;
        if self.0 > 10 {
            panic!();
        }
        next
    }
}
```

Basically, if it is possible for `R` to trigger a panic and the `T` has a destructor, you’re entering undefined behaviour, because the elements of the array may not all not be initialised at that stage. `Box<T>` is a particularly good example of such undefined behaviour, because you’ll be trying to free an undefined memory address.

This is why such usage of an array would need to either (a) have a length member to show how many of the items in the array have data so that you can skip destructors on the rest (this would require more unsafe code, of course, and simply disabling destructors is not something that is supported natively at present), or else (b) wrap each item with `Option`, setting the uninitialised values to `None` so that the illegal value’s destructor won’t be run.

Or (c) you could use vectors.

Fixed-size arrays are very much second class citizens in Rust at present.

Comment: Btw. to make initializing fixed-size arrays in a "progressive" way possible, would it suffice to have another, "array builder" type, that would be like a vector, but heap-allocated, with fixed capacity that would equal the final size of fixed-size array? After the builder have been fully initialized, it would be converted into a normal fixed-size array.

Comment: Such a mechanism would be nice to have in the future, and would help to increase the standing of arrays, but it depends on being able to express the length of an array generically. It will almost certainly happen eventually, but not for quite some time.

Comment: crate [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) implements that kind of array builder, and indeed only for a selected lot of array sizes. I fear it will not optimize so well for array building, but we have no better way to implement it in Rust right now.